# Remove an open file

Tags: python-3.x, file, operating-system, jupyter

How to remove an open file which throw permission error ?

```
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    os.close(filePath)
    os.remove(filePath)
```

It says :

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

The file is open because I'm on jupyter. It has been open because I have stopped the script before the file being closed... I need a way to close it in an other jupyter cell.

I have also tried :

```
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    f = open(filePath, "r") 
    f.close()
    os.remove(filePath)
```

And it throws

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process: 'file.txt'

Comment: What do you think "os.close(filePath)" does? Does your application have the file open, or another?

Comment: yes the app, but i'm on jupyter. It has it open because I have stopped the script before the file being closed... I need a way to close it in an other jupyter cell